# wso 2 identity server: using Facebook as identity provider

Tags: facebook, wso2, wso2-identity-server

anyone knows how to set up (if possible) wso2 identity server to have Facebook as an identity provider? 
I mean allowing users to log into my wso2is using their Facebook accounts, instead of wso2is credentials.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the upcoming WSO2 Identity Server release (4.7.0) this could be done in couple of clicks.

But if you wanted to do with current release (4.6.0) i think you have to write a Facebook authenticator.

HTH,

DarRay

Comment: I've just installed wso2is 4.7.0 milestone 1, but I can't find out how to do it.. would you explain it to me, please? thank you!

Comment: @CarloConserva WSO2 IS first milestone do not have complete capacity on this. I guess you will need to have wait until GA release.